# bzip2 version used in python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, bzip2

What is the version of bzip2 in python 3.2?

bzip2 is currently at 1.0.6.
How can I find the version used in python 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this file:
http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/PC/VC6/bz2.dsp
it's 1.0.5 but you can use this patch to upgrade:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/db97a8248863